# Снова вопрос запятые в различных примерах

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

1) Между двумя, стоящими далеко друг от друга небоскребами, прошел канатоходец.

(Как ставить запятые в причастном обороте, зависимым от сочетания числительного с существительным ?)

2) Между стоящими далеко друг от друга двумя небоскребами, прошел канатоходец.  ( запятая нужна ?)

3) Между стоящими далеко друг от друга двумя небоскребами,  я увидел канатоходца. (запятая нужна ?)

4) На уровне, примерно,  двадцатого этажа, между двумя небоскребами я увидел человека, наверное, канатоходца.  (здесь как быть с запятыми?)

Answer (score 2):

1) Между двумя стоящими далеко друг от друга небоскребами прошел канатоходец.

(Запятые не нужны: причастный оборот стоит перед определяемым словом)

2) Между стоящими далеко друг от друга двумя небоскребами прошел канатоходец. (запятая не нужна по той же причине)

3) Между стоящими далеко друг от друга двумя небоскребами я увидел канатоходца. (запятая не нужна)

4) На уровне примерно двадцатого этажа, между двумя небоскребами, я увидел человека, наверное канатоходца. ( ***Запятыми нужно выделить уточняющее обстоятельство МЕЖДУ ДВУМЯ НЕБОСКРЁБАМИ. После вводного слова НАВЕРНОЕ запятая не ставится, так как оно стоит в начале обособленного члена предложения***)

Comment: Екатерина, как вы думаете, автор на этом успокоится - или будет плодить подобные же бессмысленные вопросы?

Comment: Я полагала, что автору это действительно нужно.

Comment: Последите за его следующими вопросами, если таковые будут.